# Get an S3Object from a GetObjectResponse in AWS Java SDK 2.0

Tags: java, aws-java-sdk-2.x

In AWS Java SDK 1.x, I could get an `S3Object` from an `S3Client` like this.

```
S3Object obj = mS3Client.getObject(pBucket, pKey);
```

I'm trying to replicate that functionality using AWS Java SDK 2.0 (and end up with an `S3Object`), but the closest I can get is a `GetObjectResponse`, and I can't find any simple method calls to turn the response into an `S3Object`.

```
GetObjectResponse response = mS3Client.getObject(
        GetObjectRequest.builder()
                .bucket(pBucket)
                .key(pKey)
                .build())
        .response();
```

How can I get an `S3Object` from the 2.0 `S3Client`, or build one from the `GetObjectResponse`?

Answer (score 8):

use  ResponseInputStream. Hope the below code solves your problem.

```
GetObjectRequest request = GetObjectRequest.builder()
    .bucket("BucketName")
    .key("key")
    .build();
ResponseInputStream<GetObjectResponse> s3objectResponse = s3Client
    .getObject(request);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s3objectResponse));

String line;            
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {            
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Comment: For many different ways of converting from `InputStream` to `String`, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/309424/150884

Comment: This is helpful, but doesn't show how to get an instance of `S3Object` like the question is asking.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here, but I had to return byte array of content.

```
public byte[] getContent(String bucketName, String keyInBucket) {
    // Get Client
    S3Client s3client = getS3Client();
    // Get S3 Object
    GetObjectRequest getObjectRequest = GetObjectRequest.builder()
        .bucket(bucketName)
        .key(keyInBucket)
        .build();
    // As Byte array 
    ResponseBytes<GetObjectResponse> response = s3client.getObject(getObjectRequest, ResponseTransformer.toBytes());
    return response.asByteArray();
}
```