# Get an S3Object InputStream from a GetObjectResponse in AWS Java SDK 2 Using S3AsyncClient?

Tags: java, amazon-s3, aws-java-sdk-2.x

**How can a plain `InputStream` be created using the S3AsyncClient for a getObject request?**

The [S3AsyncClient](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/s3/S3AsyncClient.html) for AWS JDK 2.0 does not seem to have a function that returns a `ResponseInputStream<GetObjectResponse>` the same way that the S3Client synchronous client does.

The only return type available is a `CompletableFuture<GetObjectResponse>`, but the methods returning that type assume that the data is going to a local path.

```
S3AsyncClient s3AsyncClient = ...;


CompletableFuture<GetObjectResponse> response = s3AsyncClient.getObject(
    GetObjectRequest.builder()
            .bucket(bucket)
            .key(key)
            .build(),
    path));
```

There is [a similar stackoverflow item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54447306/get-an-s3object-from-a-getobjectresponse-in-aws-java-sdk-2-0), but the question and answer both utilize the synchronous S3Client.

Thank you in advance for your consideration and response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below code would get you the InputStream.

```
ResponseInputStream responseInputStream = s3AsyncClient.getObject(GetObjectRequest.builder()
        .bucket(bucket)
        .key(key)
        .build(),
        AsyncResponseTransformer.toBlockingInputStream())
```